# CentOS /dev/mapper/centos partition consumes randomly more & more storage with time

Tags: centos, filesystems, storage

On our CentOS 7.3.1611 system with installed MariaDB, httpd and Postfix the partition `/dev/mapper/centos_srv01-root` gets with more time more & more full.

- For two days (2021-07-21) is the output from df -h:
  [image: df -h output from 2021-07-21]
- The output from today:
  [image: df -h output from 2021-07-23]

We also recursively searched on the root directory for all files over 100MB. However, there were no differences between the two days. Although `/dev/mapper/centos` has 14GB more space now in use.

Does anyone have any idea what this could be due to and any suggested solutions?

Comment: A common cause for mysterious space shortages is deleting (or truncating) files while they are open - the space used by the file isn't released until the process holding the file open ends.  You could try doing a `lsof | grep deleted` to see if any such files exist and their size.

Comment: @dennis you may use `du -md1 /` do see in Megabyte were it goes, i bet some crazy logfile directory is going strange

Comment: Hi @BrandonXavier, unfortunately this is not the solution :(

Answer (score 0):

After your search for large files, presumably the problem is not files over 100 MB in size.

Use a directory size utility where you can navigate the tree.  `ncdu` is a text (curses) based one, and for RHEL it is in EPEL repository.

```
ncdu -x /
```

On a multiple purpose host with database, web and mail, could be anything.

After identifying what is growing, assess if it is useful to keep. Debug verbosity log files might not be useful, consider turning off or purging with `logrotate`. Or, if it is a database containing useful information, account for the growth rate in your capacity planning.